# Extra argument 'mobileNumber' in call

Tags: ios, swift, mode

I have been sitting for a while with this error , i even checked stack overflow similar questions but non helped. I am getting this error and i do not know what i am doing wrong.

This is the eror image, due to less points i cant post it but i can embed a this link.
[image: This is the eror image, due to less points i cant post it but i can embed a this link.]

This is my code where the error is occurring :

```
class SearchViewModelFromSearchResult: SearchCustomerModel 
{

    var search: SearchResultObj?

    init() 
    {
        self.search = SearchResultObj()
    }

    func searchDataRequested(_ apiUrl: String,_ country: String,_ phone:String) 
    {

        let service = ServiceCall(urlServiceCall: apiUrl, country: country, phone: phone)
        let url = URL(string: apiUrl)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let country = country
        let phone = phone

        service.fetchJson(request: request, customerCountry: country, mobileNumber: phone)
         { (ok, json) in
            print("CallBack response : \(String(describing: json))")
            self.jsonMappingToSearch(json!)
        }
    }
....
```

Service call class :

```
class ServiceCall: NSObject, ServiceCallProtocol, URLSessionDelegate 
{
    let urlServiceCall: String?
    let country: String?
    let phone: String?

    init(urlServiceCall: String,country: String, phone: String)
    {
        self.urlServiceCall = urlServiceCall
        self.country = country
        self.phone = phone
    }

    func fetchJson(request: URLRequest, customerCountry: String, mobileNumber: String)
    {
        let searchParamas = CustomerSearch.init(country: customerCountry, phoneNumber: mobileNumber)
        var request = request
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try?  searchParamas.jsonData()
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                let status = json["status"] as? Bool
                if status == true {

                }else{

                }
            } catch {
               print("Unable to make an api call")
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swift compiler's error messages are sometimes extremely misleading. When an error doesn't seem to make sense, step back and treat the error as the compiler saying "Derp? Something is wrong with this line, but I am confused so I'm going to make up a random message that makes no sense and let you figure it out." Andrew gave you the actual error in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, `fetchJson` doesn't have a completion parameter, but when you called it, you write:

```
{ (ok, json) in
```

Please change your function declaration to this:

```
func fetchJson(request: URLRequest, customerCountry: String, mobileNumber: String, completion: ((Bool, Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> Void)?)
```

Comment: how do i get the json response object from the completion handler

Comment: You don't get the response object **from** the completion handler. The response object is passed **into** the completion handler.